# Interesting properties in $...\to K(\mathbb{Z}_4,1) \overset{f}{\to} K(\mathbb{Z}_2,1)\overset{g}{\to}K(\mathbb{Z}_2,2) \to ...$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, group-cohomology, classifying-spaces

Let $K(G,n)$ be the Eilenberg Maclane space.

Consider the map from
$$
K(\mathbb{Z}_2,1) \to K(\mathbb{Z}_4,1) \overset{f}{\to} K(\mathbb{Z}_2,1)\overset{g}{\to}K(\mathbb{Z}_2,2) \to \dots,
$$

It looks that we can represent the map from $K(\mathbb{Z}_2,1)\to K(\mathbb{Z}_2,2)$ 
relating to the
generator of cohomology group
$$
q \in H^2(K(\mathbb{Z}_2,1),\mathbb{Z}_2)=H^2(B\mathbb{Z}_2,\mathbb{Z}_2)=\mathbb{Z}_2.
$$

Say 
$$
p \in H^1(K(\mathbb{Z}_2,1),\mathbb{Z}_2)=H^1(B\mathbb{Z}_2,\mathbb{Z}_2)=\mathbb{Z}_2,
$$
then $q$ and $p$ are group cocycles related by
$$
q = p \cup p.
$$

1. Roughly, say due to the exact sequence above, we may say the **kernel** (in $K(\mathbb{Z}_2,1)$) of the map $g$, such that 
   $$
   q = p \cup p =0, 
   $$
   matches
   the **image** (in $K(\mathbb{Z}_2,1)$) of
   $$
   f. 
   $$
2. Can we see explicitly that $q = p \cup p$ may be non-zero in $H^2(K(\mathbb{Z}_2,1),\mathbb{Z}_2)=H^2(B\mathbb{Z}_2,\mathbb{Z}_2)=\mathbb{Z}_2$, but $q =0$ when we pull back via $f$ from the $K(\mathbb{Z}_2,1)$ to $K(\mathbb{Z}_4,1)$? Can this be demonstrated explicitly at the level of group cocycle?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Represent $p$ by the identity map $id: \mathbb{Z}_2 \to \mathbb{Z}_2$. 
Then $(p\cup p)(a,b) = p(a)p(b)$ is non-zero only on the 2-chain $(1,1)$. Namely, as a polynomial mod 2, $(p\cup p)(a,b) = ab$. When lifted to $\mathbb{Z}_4$, we get $p\cup p(a,b)=ab \mod 2$. Consider the function $\gamma: \mathbb{Z}_4\to \mathbb{Z}_2$ defined by $\gamma(x) = \frac{x^2-x}{2} \mod{2}$, namely $\gamma(0)=0,\gamma(1)=0,\gamma(2)=1,\gamma(3)=1$. Then 
$$d\gamma(x,y)=\gamma(x+y)-\gamma(x)-\gamma(y)=xy,$$ by 
$(x+y)^2-x^2-y^2 + (x +y)-x-y=2xy$. Note that $\gamma$ is really well defined because always $x^2 \equiv x \mod 2$ and you can see that if you add a multiple of $4$ to $x$ it don't changes the residue mod $2$ of the answer. So $d\gamma = p\cup p$ in $C^2(\mathbb{Z}_4,\mathbb{Z}_2)$.

Comment: @S. carmeli I change your $g$ to $\gamma$ due to that $g$ was usef in OP differently, then also correct $d\gamma(x,y)=\gamma(x+y)-\gamma(x)-\gamma(y)=xy,$ please see whether it maintains your meanings

Comment: Can you provide me a hint how do you obtain this answer and the idea behind it?

Comment: I guess the point here is that polynomial functions on $\mathbb{Z}/4$ has the bad property that they preserve equivalences mod $2$. This means that in order to obtain new relations you need non-polynomial functions, and the simplest example is a polynomial that is always even for non trivial reason, divided by 2. So you can consider it as a usage of the fact that the binomial ${n\choose 2}$ is always an integer!

Comment: I just post a new question, may be you also knew the answer - see the link.

Comment: @wonderich its fine.

Comment: @annieheart which link? I don't see it if you mention the question title it will be easy to locate.